# How to create an Arrow Symbol

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a way to create a symbol of an arrow in which it points in a downward direction but do not know if one already exist. I have tried `detexify` to come up with nothing.

The picture of the arrow is below:

[image: Picture of Arrow]

Comment: See "Table 110: `mathabx` Arrows" of http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf . If you manage to turn the symbol `\Rsh` by 90° to the right you've got your symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `TikZ` you can define a command that will give you a stretchable symbol; you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myarrow[1][1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0) -- (#1,0); \draw[->] (#1,0) -- (#1,-0.5);\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\myarrow[6.4]
\begin{equation}
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{equation}

\noindent\myarrow[4.8]
\begin{equation}
  a= b + c + d + e + f.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Gonzalo: Thanks again. It works like a charm and the best part about this solution is that it is easy to maintain, i.e., make adjustments to fit your ones particular needs with some minor changes. Thanks Again. :) Gotta learn this `tikz` package to draw things. I have `inkscape`, but have not done much with it yet.

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}

\newcommand{\rRsh}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\Rsh$}}
```

Try $X\rRsh Y$ and make your comments.

If **mathabx** is loaded instead of **amssymb**, the same definition produces a symbol with two equal segments.

To get an extensible horizontal bar, define

```
\newcommand{\longrRsh}[1]{%
  \makebox[#1]{\leaders\hrule height 1.25ex depth -1.16ex\relax
    \hfil\kern-1pt\rRsh}}
```

and then `\longrRsh{3cm}` will produce a 3cm long symbol (the figures are optimized for the **amssymb** version).

Comment: @ egreg:Thanks! It worked very well. Could you add a little extension on the the already good answer to show how to extend the arrow longer to the right?

Comment: Not quite what I meant, but I see the difference in the suggestion stated above. I wanted the segment that does not have the arrow tip connected to it to stretch across the page to a certain spot to point down right over a set of equations.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite what you are looking for but might be good enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[
    a \rhookdownarrow b
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I might find that symbol helpful later. But not quite what I was needing at the moment.